# in the dimension of depth and breadth？

Tags: sentence

I would like to write something like:

This is a comprehensive book---in the dimension of depth, it covers the topic A, and in the dimension of breadth, it covers topic B.

（Topic A is a deep technical area, whereas topic B is a broad one)

What is the best way to say it?

Comment: Both broad and deep.

Comment: Do you mind providing a full sentence?

Comment: This book is both broad and deep, covering topic a in depth and topic B broadly. (Lots of ways to say it.)

Comment: Hmm, the sentence does seem to carry the meaning I would like to have. (Perhaps I was not clear enough before.) I wanted to say that topic a is the deepest in the book, whereas topic B is the most broad in the spectrum of breath. The sentence you have seems to say that the book only has topic A and B. Also I'm wondering whether broad and dee and in depth, broadly are a bit repetitive.

Comment: You’ll have to try it different ways.

Comment: *In this comprehensive book, A is the deepest topic, and B is the broadest topic.*